# Codeship cloning another repository from one repository

Tags: codeship

I have created a repository on the codeship and push my code on that repository. I have another repository which is dependent on the this repository.When i am trying to create the build it is going to clone the   another repository.I am getting access denied error.I can not add two codeship key to one project.

Can anyone please help me out for this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a build url that you could share here? Sounds like you'll need to add the CodeShip project's public ssh key to the additional repositories -- https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/builds-and-configuration/access-to-other-repositories